# Laravel 5.4 hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

can someone please explain how the hasManyThrough relates to the sql statement I am trying to acheive?

```
 --offers table
    id, network_id, mobile_id

--networks table
    id, name

--mobiles table
   id, name
```

I am trying to get Mobile::with('networks')

I would write this as

```
SELECT DISTINCT networks.name from networks, offers where offers.network_id = networks.id and offers.mobile_id in (1,2,3,4)
```

In relation to the above sql statement where does each arg live in the hasManyThrough method? i.e

```
hasManyThrough(Network::class,Offer::class,'network_id','mobile_id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is many to many relationship

```
 --offers table
    id, network_id, mobile_id

--networks table
    id, name

--mobiles table
   id, name
```

Network Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Network extends Model
{
    public function mobile(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Mobile', 'offers')->withPivot('mobile_id');
    }    
}
```

Mobile Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mobile extends Model
{
    public function network(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Network', 'offers')->withPivot('network_id');
    }    
}
```

You may use pivot to fetch relationship
For more info visit [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

However for such conditions you must use a pivot table, i.e mobile_network instead of offers.

Comment: I was trying to avoid an extra pivot table as the offers table is alreay a pivot containing all the id's needed but I think you are right thanks.